# how can we use a batch file in c++?

Tags: c++, batch-file

MY PURPOSE: I want to make a c++ program that could use DOS commands.

OPTION: I can make a batch file and put into it the DOS commands.
        But I don't know how to use this file from a c++ program?

Answer (score 15):

There are two options available to run batch files on Windows from C/C++.

First, you can use [system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) (or _wsystem for wide characters).

> "The system function passes command to the command interpreter, which executes the string as an operating-system command. system refers to the COMSPEC and PATH environment variables that locate the command-interpreter file (the file named CMD.EXE in Windows 2000 and later)."

Or you can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) directly.

Note that for batch files:

> "To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file."

Comment: Is `::CreateProcess(L"cmd.exe"` really works ? I got error 2, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. BUT, In the same call, if I replace with `L"c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"`, then it miraculously works ...

Answer (score 13):

```
system("mybatchfile.bat");
```

[system() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/)

Comment: Worked at fist attempt. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
//example that makes and then calls a batch file

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ofstream batch;
    batch.open("mybatchfile.bat", ios::out);

    batch <<"@echo OFF\n";
    batch <<":START\n";
    batch <<"dir C:\n";
    batch <<"myc++file 2 >nul\n";
    batch <<"goto :eof\n";

    batch.close();

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        system("mybatchfiles.bat");
        cout <<"Starting Batch File...\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to look at the `system`, `ShellExecute`, and `CreateProcess` calls, to figure out which one is appropriate in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Putting dos commands inside batch script seems like a good idea. Then you can of course use `system` command.

But if your C++ program also needs stdout of the batch script you were running, you should try: `_popen` or `_wpopen`.

For more info and code sample visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use system call in c++ program to execute all the commands that C++ program gets from the user.