# Run a command with parameter from c++ program

Tags: c++, c, windows, command-line, pipe

I want to run an `.exe` file from my c++ program.
but I also want to pipe an input file and take output of that file into another file.

I know that this can be done from command line as:

```
c:> my_program.exe <"input.txt"> "output.txt"
```

with this command, my_program takes all standard input from `input.txt` and gives standard output to `output.txt`

Now I want this should happen from my C++ program.
my `my_program.exe` is in D: drive. also `input.tx`t is in D: drive.

Please tell me how can I accomplish my goal.

Comment: Why don t you just cd to D:?

Comment: @DrakaSAN
I want that command to be run from c++ or c program

Comment: You mean [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478171/how-can-we-use-a-batch-file-in-c)

Comment: yes actually, but i dont know batch programming

Comment: Please explain your goal. If you want to read and write to file, there is fopen, fprintf, fscanf and fclose. If you want to run batch from c++, there is system. If you want to use D drive, you need to cd into it.

Comment: Or you want to redirect stdin and stdout from inside of your program?

Comment: Yes I want to redirect stdin to input.txt and stout to output.txt for another program.

Comment: Could you accept the answer that helped you, so anyone having the same problem and ending up here can know what was the solution? It also help thoses who crawl the "unanswered question" to avoid losing time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle input and output pipes inside your c++ program, and read/write data to files accordingly. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The question was basically how to redirect stdin and stdout from the inside of C++, which as been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files).

Answer (score -1):

Just change your directory to D:

cd D:\

D:>my_program.exe <"input.txt">"output.txt"

Comment: this is not what I want.
I want a c++ program to do this.
I dont want to do it manually.
My C++ program should do it automatically