# Would like to run PowerShell code from inside a C++ program

Tags: c++, powershell

I want to be able to run like 30 lines of PowerShell script from my c++ program. I've heard it's a terrible idea, I don't care. I still would like to know how.

I just want to code directly in the C++ program, i do not want to externally call the PowerShell script. Is there any way to do this? If it's impossible, just say no.

For example

```
void runPScode() {

//command to tell compiler the following is PowerShell code
//a bunch of PowerShell code

}
```

Thanks!

I've looked for commands to do this and have read several 'similar' questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This just for completeness' sake:

---

PowerShell has an API - see [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0). The API is managed (i. e. .NET-based). It's possible to build a mixed mode C++ application and invoke said API from the managed part.

Place the following into a separate C++ file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vcclr.h>
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Management.Automation.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Management::Automation;

void RunPowerShell(LPCWSTR s)
{
    PowerShell::Create()->AddScript(gcnew String(s))->Invoke();
}
```

In Project Properties, under VC++ Directories, add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0` to Reference Directories (your path may vary).

Set the following compiler options **for that file only**:

- Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)
- Debug information format - Program Database (/Zi)
- Enable C++ exceptions - No
- Basic runtime checks - Default
- Precompiled header - Not Using Precompiled Headers

You need `/clr` for calling .NET from C++, but `/clr` is incompatible with a bunch of other C++ options. If you miss something, the compiler error messages will let you know.

Declare `void RunPowerShell(LPCWSTR)` as a regular external function in the unmanaged parts of the project, invoke as needed.

---

That said, **whatever your Powershell does, C++/Win32 probably can do too**. That said, some one-line features of Powershell (e. g. the remoting) would translate into hundreds of lines of C++.

Comment: With my Visual Studio 2019, I had to use "Conformance Mode: No (/permissive)" too.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> //command to tell compiler the following is PowerShell code
> ```

No! There's no such command to tell the compiler, and

> ```
> //a bunch of PowerShell code ...
> ```

being executed inline.

You can achieve this using the [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function choosing your shell, and provide it with the appropriate code to execute.

Comment: Inline - no, in-process - yes. The PowerShell scripting engine is perfectly programmable.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: using system or `CreateProcess`. The system documentation is found at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019

Using this method you pass a string command. An example, as shown in the documentation:

```
system( "type crt_system.txt" );
```

CreateProcess documentation is found at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa

Using this command is a little trickier and I wouldn't recommend it for simple commands.

For additional information please see:
[how can we use a batch file in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478171)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the specific method and explanation in your answer and link to the website as a reference, rather than just linking out to an external resource.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: those answers are for the command prompt, i'm using powershell, are the commands the same?

Comment: He has more than two options. There's also [the exec family](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html).

Comment: Can the exec family be used for command prompt? I thought it was used specifically for bash commands

Answer (score 0):

How I do it at work... is just with a shortcut on the desktop... what's even more tricky? Getting XAML to pin on the taskbar...

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle hidden -File "C:\Users\USER01\Documents\scripts\runClassModule.ps1"
```

and just set the shortcut with this target.

So that in c++ ... just call out the shortcut...

```
system("c:\\users\\USER01\Desktop\\yourshortcut\\shortcut.lnk") ;
```

or just the code itself

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle hidden -File C:\\Users\\USER01\\Documents\\myApp\\modulesScripts\\runClassModule.ps1");
```

This opens a variety of win32 apps and forms I use for automatic motion.

Going all the way and adding a password while examining some of the codes used by the shell....

```
 system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\runas.exe  /profile  /user:MYDOMAIN\\USER01\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle hidden -File C:\\Users\\USER01\\Documents\\myApp\\modules\\runClassModule.ps1\"");
```